DNS: solution to provide response based of source AS number?
I need to dynamically serve DNS responses based on the source IP address  Autonomous System (AS) number.
My current
setup uses Cloudflare as a DNS-only provider. Due to network
restrictions, I need to direct traffic from specific Internet Service
Providers (ISPs).
I've researched geolocation-based DNS management, but all my customers are
located in a single country. Instead, I need to return results
based on the AS number to determine the ISP. If not possible to use the source IP address, use source
IP ranges. This would allow me to export IP ranges associated with each
ISP under their respective ASN.
Question: Is it possible to use a cloud-based DNS solution with the required features, or
do I need to run my own on-premises DNS server to achieve these results?

I could be wrong here, but I don't think DNS explicitly provides support for ASNs. You need whois data for that. Most DNS servers will allow for split horizon behaviour - usually driven by client IP address. But running an authoritative public DNS server is not a good idea unless you know exactly what you're doing.

Is it feasible to use any cloud-based DNS solution

Any cloud based DNS solution? No. And product recommendations are off topic here. If you want to drive the responses based on ASN numbers then your choice is likely to be very limited. Also bear in mind that where the client is located is not the same thing as where the DNS server asking on behalf of the client is are not the same thing.

im not sure thats why i asked here, also about your last line i also heard that when i was searching for using bind as a source based dns server i think in theory edns feature is what i need in that case but idk if thats doable
